# Firebase Javascript retrieve a user details using UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve a user details only using it's UID, I want it because I want to show my users their list of friends, I have checked the documentation on Firebase Auth., It seems to be only supported in 'admin' section. Should I save my user data in the database instead of Auth. or Is there a way to do it without using Firebase Auth. in my server ? I am running a web application and using Javascript to manipulate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to list or query Firebase Auth accounts directly from a web or mobile app.  That would be a security problem, and that's why it's limited to admin/backend access only via the Firebase Admin SDK.

If you do want anyone to be able to find other user accounts, you will need to store that user data in your database, or provide a backend API endpoint that it can access.